# How to get rank of a user from all users

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table called summary_coins , By ranking of coins I am trying to get an user ranking

I have tried like below

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    sum(get_count),
    rank() over (order by sum(get_count) asc) as rank 
FROM summary_coins 
WHERE user_id = 2
GROUP BY user_id
```

sample data , `without user_id = 2 in where` I am getting below list

```
user_id sum rank
44      2    1
13      4    2
57      4    2
47      4    2
11      5    5
2       5    5
```

My desire out put :

```
2       5    5
```

Here I am always getting ranking 1 for user ID 2 , But from list of user it should be rank 5.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Please, provide sample data and desired output in text format. Currently there's no any user ID and no one can tell you, why you get the same rank for some values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply `WHERE user_id = 2` late. `RANK OVER` is the last thing to happen in your query, but you want to apply the `WHERE` clause afterwards. In order to do this make your query a subquery you select from:

```
SELECT user_id, sum_count, rank
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    user_id,
    sum(get_count) AS sum_count,
    rank() over (order by sum(get_count) asc) as rank 
  FROM summary_coins 
  GROUP BY user_id
) all_users
WHERE user_id = 2;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this query be slow if the number of users increase? Is there no way to have a constant query time even if number of users increase?

Comment: @Vaulstein: It is true that this a rather slow process, because we must aggregate all rows and then rank them in order to get the result. But that's how it is. If we wanted to avoid this, we would have to store the rank or at least the sums redundantly and write them via triggers. That would slow down the inserts and updates, but speed up the query.

Comment: Found another way to do this which is faster - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table

- Get sum_count for user 
- Get how many more have sum_count > user

Comment: @Vaulstein: Thank you for looking this up and mentioning it here. You are right; as we are only interested in the rank of one user, we can simply see how many users have a lesser sum. I didn't think of this when writing my answer and still didn't when you asked me about my query's performance problems, but it is probably the best solution.

Comment: Yes, even I found it from the solution mentioned on the link shared. cheers!